# Change elements of ul on click

Tags: javascript

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

The element that is clicked should get a red color, bold and italic font.

Comment: What have you actually tried? It is almost trivial to do it with (1) [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and (2) [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Yes it is trivial, but I just started learning javascript.

Comment: Then make use of the search function: this is easily covered by many questions that have been asked before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add id to your ul and use it for event listener

```
ulId.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  if(e.target.nodeName==="LI"){
    e.target.style.cssText = "color:red;font-weight:bold; font-style:italic";
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best solution but it works

```js
function clicker(liID){
   document.getElementById('item' + liID).style.color = "magenta";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="item1" onClick="clicker(1)">First</li>
  <li id="item2" onClick="clicker(2)">Second</li>
  <li id="item3" onClick="clicker(3)">Third</li>
</ul>
```